# Can a lower triangular matrix be positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

One of my classes describes a matrix as lower triangular AND positive definite. But a positive definite matrix must be symmetric, and it is not clear to me how a matrix can have the following two properties simultaneously (unless it were also diagonal, and not merely lower triangular): (i) all the entries above the main diagonal are zero and (ii) it is symmetric. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: A diagonal matrix can be also positive definite. Think that.

Comment: So that's the only way to explain this I suppose. So the matrix is not merely lower triangular, but diagonal (and positive definite)

Comment: In some contexts, positive definite matrices need not be symmetric. In this context, $A$ is called "positive definite" when the symmetric matrix $A + A^T$ is positive definite in the usual sense.